# Resourcenotfound exception for setting vector drawable as background on textview

Tags: android, textview, android-vectordrawable

I am running my app on API level 22 and setting the vector image as background to my text view

And I get the exception

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bg_rect_mcorner_cards.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070073
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2904)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2772)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3791)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:674)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:669)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:100)
```

This is my vector image

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="155dp"
android:height="19dp"
android:viewportWidth="155"
android:viewportHeight="19">
<path
  android:pathData="M0,0H155C155,10.493 146.493,19 136,19H19C8.507,19 0,10.493 0,0Z">
      <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
  <gradient
      android:startY="0"
      android:startX="77.5"
      android:endY="19"
      android:endX="77.5"
      android:type="linear">
    <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FF63D8FF"/>
    <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FF6397FF"/>
  </gradient>
</aapt:attr>
</path>
</vector>
```

And I am setting this on textview as background

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/comingSoon_TV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_mcorner_cards"
            android:text="@string/coming_soon"
             />
```

In app gradle

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

What is the workaround to make it work on api level 22?